# Issues in validating CSS3

Tags: css, w3c-validation

Here is my CSS3 code.

```
body
{
    background-color: #fdf4d5;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #C80000;
}
a:active
{
    background-color: #C80000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.body
{
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
}
.mainHeader img
{
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainHeader nav
{
    background-color: #faa01e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 15px 80px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active, .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a.visited
{
    background: #C80000;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainContent
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 25px;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.content
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 70%;
}
.content img
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content p:first-letter
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content p
{
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Adobe Caslon Pro", "Hoefler Text", Georgia, Garamond, Times, serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    line-height: 145%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.bottomContent
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 0;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.boxOne
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
}
.boxTwo
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
}
.boxOne img
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.boxTwo img
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainFooter
{
    background-color: #FAA01E;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 0;
    moz-border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainFooter p
{
    color: #FFF;
    float: right;
    margin: 2% auto;
    width: 92%;
}
```

I have used the following website to validate the code.
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Once I validated it I have received lot of errors.In fact 22 errors and 10 warnings!
I'm a newbie who is learning html5 and css3 on my own.I'm really happy I have come this far.But I need some help from experts like you to correct the errors.
I just corrected my html5 code relating to this css3 code with some help from this forum.But it had only 1 error.But this is too much.
What went wrong?
Please help me.Thank you very much.

Comment: i dont see anything obviously wrong, why dont you copy the output of the validator to https://gist.github.com or similar if you are having trouble understanding what its telling you?

Comment: As I said earlier I'm a newbie to html5 and css3.html5 page which is related to this css3 is working fine.But when I validate this css3 code I receved lot of errors.I need to know why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **wrong properties** for your Mozilla and Webkit compatibility.

You have:

```
moz-border-radius:
webkit-border-radius:
```

**And it should be**

```
-moz-border-radius:
-webkit-border-radius:
```

Actually you can just use `border-radius`.  But that's where the errors are coming from.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!
I'll change them and re-validate it.

Comment: Feel free to click "Accept" (green checkmark) if the answer works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using proprietary properties without a `-` before their names, so you need to do that.

For example `moz-border-radius` should be

```
  -moz-border-radius
--^--
```

same goes for `-webkit` properties as well, so `webkit-border-radius` should be

```
  -webkit-border-radius
--^--
```

---

Also, you can click on *More Options* to get a precised validation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!
I'll change them and re-validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Validator complains about usage of incorrect prefixes `moz-` and `webkit-`. You should add dashes in front of them. But better remove them all together. So the next rules are not needed:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

and you can safely use

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

unless you want to support couple of old browsers. All modern browsers support `border-radius` without prefixes. See support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!
I'll change them and re-validate it.